# Vue Dev Tools - Vuex not clickable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Something that has started occurring recently - the Vuex icon within Vue Dev Tools in Chrome has become unresponsive. I am using the following Vue versions within a webpack build along with Vue Dev Tools 3.1.6.

```
"vue": "^2.1.0",
"vue-router": "^2.7.0",
"vuex": "^2.3.1"
```

The Vuex icon is totally unresponsive (ie you can't click on it) although Vuex is working fine within the context of the application.  The component icon within Vue Dev Tools works fine. I should note that occasionally Vuex (the Vuex icon is clickable) will work within Dev Tools (about 10% of the time).

I've tried reinstalling Vue dev tools but no change noticed.

Very frustrating so any help appreciated!

Comment: Adding a (somewhat hacky) solution in case anyone else has the same problem.  I have a two monitor setup (laptop + external screen) - if I have chrome dev tools open on my external screen the Vuex icon is not clickable. However if I move Chrome dev tools down to my laptop screen then everything can be clicked.  Weird but glad its working again!

Comment: Chrome Dev Tool is actually having issues, they eat up alot of memory, get hang sometime, also get crashed often.
The patch solution i found is that if you found that dev tool unresponsive, just resize the dev tool bar. It start working normally after that.

Comment: Also, make sure don't keep actively open dev tool while switching from one route to another.
- Firefox dev tool with Quantum is quite good as compared to chrome dev tool!

Comment: For me undocking the dev tools fixed it.